# How can I run an application on a remote machine by ssh?

Tags: java, linux, ssh, remote-access, jsch

How can I run an application on a remote machine via ssh?

I tried using JSCH, this way:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    String host = "111.111.11.111";
    String user = "myuser";
    String pwd = "mypass";
    // int port = 22;

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
    session.setConfig(props);
    session.setPassword(pwd);
    session.connect();

    System.out.println(session.getServerVersion());
    System.out.println("Conected!");

    // String command = "ps -ef;date;hostname";

    String command = "myapplication  someFileAsParameter";
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

    // channel.setInputStream(System.in);
    channel.setInputStream(null);

    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

    channel.connect();
```

and I have this:

*bash: myapplication: command not found*

When try execute this command by shell, works fine.

Not necessarily needs to be JSCH, can be anything.

Comment: Does this works if you use command line ssh? `ssh myuser@111.111.11.111 myapplication  someFileAsParameter`

Comment: Are you sure the command is in your PATH when logged in via JSch? I have a vague feeling there could be a login vs. non-login shell issue here.

Comment: @Paulo Does! but I need to insert the password. And does using ps

Comment: @qid Im doing that /usr/local/myapp/mySH    /myfolder/myFileAsParameter

Comment: @coffee: the `ssh` test was only to locate the problem, not a solition proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For future readers**: As shown by the discussion, the reason was that JSch connected to a different server than normal SSH (and one of these had the file, while the other one had not). I still let my answer here, as it contains some useful (I think) debugging ideas for similar problems. But remember: **First check that you are connecting to the right computer**.

---

In principle, this is the way to do it, if you use JSch. If you get the error message `bash: myapplication: command not found`, this means that there was no `myapplication` binary in the path. (And you will get the same error message when using plain command line `ssh`.)

Try `which myapplication` (or `type myapplication`) in your normal shell, to see where it is located. Then use `echo $PATH >&2` as the command, to see the path used by your exec channel. It could be that this is different then when executed from your normal shell. If so, either use the full path in the command name, or fix your setup. (Look wether the path is set in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Only some of these files will get executed on a interactive versus noninteractive login - and `exec` channel will be noninteractive, I think.)

Comment: Works fine when I did this way: `ssh myuser@111.111.11.111 myapplication someFileAsParameter`. And my application is in /usr/local/bin and my PATH is /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: @Paulo So, my path is correct, right? Why it works when I use command line? Thank you.

Comment: I don't really have an idea here ... did you use your `echo $PATH` from the shell or from JSch?

Comment: Also, does `/usr/local/bin/myapplication someFileAsParameter` (in JSch) work?

Comment: echo $PATH -> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
...Using JSch didnt work. 
Only using `ssh myuser@111.111.11.111 myapplication someFileAsParameter`, but with interactive login

Comment: This looks really strange. Are you sure you are connecting to the same server? What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/myapplication` show (from JSch)?

Comment: I am very ashamed. different machines. Thanks!