# Push script to remote system then run it

Tags: java, jsch

I am writing a java program to help automate several tasks. In one of these tasks I need to push a bash script to a remote linux system (the java program will be running on a windows box) and then run the script. Does anyone have and idea how one would go about doing this?

Ive looked into Jsch but the documentation is terrible and I am having an incredibly difficult time implementing what I want to do.  Any other ideas or specific usecases?

EDIT: I just had the idea of using java to run a batch that may do this. Convoluted yes but maybe possible. Looking into this now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an application on a remote machine by ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527406/how-can-i-run-an-application-on-a-remote-machine-by-ssh) and [Scp file with jsch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991794/scp-file-with-jsch-gives-unexpected-filename) - you'll note there's *lots* of infofrmation here on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Yes thank you. My googlefoo is clearly weak. I had searched each of these requirements separately but never returned those results, and in asking this question the related questions didnt include those either. I will use those links and see if I can cobble something together. Thank you.

Comment: If this is an ongoing requirement you might want to look at system management tools like Salt or Puppet (there are may others out there).

Answer (score 0):

I did create a [Javadoc for JSch](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/), which should help you do this. For copying you should use the ChannelSftp, and then ChannelExec to execute the script.

Alternatively, if you don't really need the script to be on the server, depending on the scripting language, you might be able to provide your whole script as the "command" of ChannelExec (its command is executed in the user's default shell, and has no inherent size limit, I think).

If you are using Perl or a similar interpreter, you can pass the script as the standard input (i.e. the channel's input stream) to the interpreter command, which should allow to execute it "live".